# How To Implement Full Text Search In Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, full-text-search

How can i implement full text search in laravel 5.2. Which is the best way to do it. or is there any other alternative available?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `like` statement but will be slower or Have a look at [Elastiquent](http://www.fullstackstanley.com/read/simple-search-with-laravel-and-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 0):

[Sofa/Eloquence](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence) seems to be a nice solution.